# Add GPU at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Then I try to make a new instance I get an error

[image]

I made a request to the support team to increase the quota to 2

[image]

but I cannot create an instance even with one GPU

[image]

I do everything according to the instructions, but they do not work. Help solve the problem please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first screenshot and increased quota in us-east1-c, you need to increase GPU quota [globally](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#regional_and_global_quotas) as well. Projects have a global GPU quota that applies to all regions.

Also, I recommend you to edit your screenshots to remove your project ID as it is visible in public.